# TypeError: require.extensions.hasOwnProperty is not a function

Tags: laravel, gulp, vagrant

I am setting a gulp installation on windows 10 for laravel,After I installing a npm,python and node
and I installed the gulp also ,AfterThat i run the

```
gulp like
```

command,it shows the following error message , I dont know where i mistake

Here Versions I installed

> npm
>   --6.9.0
>
> node
>   --10.15.3
>
> python 
>   2.7.16
>
> gulp
>
> ClI Version
>   --2.1.0 Local Version
>   --3.9.1

And I also installed gulp globally using following command

```
npm install -g gulp
```

i checked the npm update using following command globally

```
npm install npm-check-updates -g
```

After all i execute the gulp command it shows following error

```
$ gulp like
```

> C:\cygwin64\home\D-218\workspace\shima\src\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\require-dir\index.js:93
>               if (!require.extensions.hasOwnProperty(ext)) {
>                                       ^
>
> TypeError: require.extensions.hasOwnProperty is not a function
>       at requireDir (C:\cygwin64\home\D-218\workspace\shima\src\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\require-dir\index.js:93:37)
>       at Elixir (C:\cygwin64\home\D-218\workspace\shima\src\node_modules\laravel-elixir\index.js:2:27)
>       at Object. (C:\cygwin64\home\D-218\workspace\shima\src\tasks\admin.js:34:1)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)

Answer (score 2):

Try to update `require-dir` to version 0.3.2, after that remove `node_modules`, and `npm install`. Hope it helps.